# Average Document Length in Okapi BM25

Tags: information-retrieval

I am studying the Okapi BMS25 model. I understand everything but two confusion. While calculating document length (dl) and average document length (avdl). I found the document length is

[image]

So it is a summation of my keywords/terms in a particular document. But when I see wiki's def:

[image]

So |D| is the length of the document D in words (i.e. is summation of total words count). 
Now, the question what is dl actually?

Now, second question how to calculate avdl? (just calculating (doc1+doc2+...N)/N where N is my total no documents in collection? (and avdl is fixed for whole collection?)

Answer (score 7):

According the Joaquín Pérez-Iglesias in [Integrating the Probabilistic Model BM25/BM25F into Lucene](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5046), the score function R should be defined as followed :

[image]

such as

- `occurs_t^d` is the term frequency of `t` in `d`,
- `l_d` is the document `d` length.
- `avl_d` is the document average length along the collection
- `k_1` is a free parameter usually 2 and `b` in [0,1] (usually 0.75).

Assigning 0 to `b` is equivalent to avoid the process of normalisation and therefore the document length will not affect the final score.

If `b` takes 1, we will be carrying out a full length normalisation.

[image]

where `N` is the number of document in the collection and `df` is the number of documents where appears the term `t`.

Comment: Really nice when someone takes the time to explain the maths. Cheers

Comment: Where does the idf(t) gets accounted in the R(q,d) formula? Where does it get used?